# Npm install difference

Tags: node.js, npm, installation

When I install npm package like this:

```
npm install ngx-popover
```

I got flattern files structure.

But when I install it directly from github like this:

```
npm install github:pleerock/ngx-popover
```

I received the same files structure as in original repo.

So I wounder where are this hidden step for making flatter files strucrure done?
I cannot find any postinstall on package.js. Can someone explain why this is hapenig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing `npm install ngx-popover`, you're querying the [registry](https://registry.npmjs.org/ngx-popover) of npmjs.org, which contains a link to a compressed (tarball) version of the package.

If you install it from github, npm is *"simply"* cloning the repository.

The real magic here happens in [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-popover/blob/master/gulpfile.ts). The author of this project has made an automated script that cleans up the source code and creates a flattened version ready to be packed and published to npmjs' registry.

Comment: Ok thank you! And what I need to do if I want to fork this module do some fixed there and then substitute original with fixed. Why this automated build scripts is not called from my forked project?

Comment: *(Note: the following instructions are specific to this package)* You should run `npm install` from inside the package folder, which will install the dev dependencies. Then, try running `gulp -T` (install gulp with `npm install -g gulp` if you haven't already). It should print the commands available. In this case, it looks like `gulp package` would do what you're trying to do.